# Howto to install a Tor middle relay on a working Windows VPN Proxy?

Tags: relays, windows, proxy, vpn

I've looked through the existing descriptions and tried many ways to do this - but don't believe it's ever worked for me.

I have a Windows 7 pro machine which has been running for years with only two applications - Open VPN and Privoxy. Both run from a guest account and supply web access & DNS to all other PCs here. This machine runs 24/7.

Would like to install a manually started tor middle relay, but it sems everything I try fails to get the torrc recognized by the tor.exe file. But when I manually start tor.exe with admin priviledges from that same guest account - it indicates it can build working circuits from it's default.

I don't need tor access (have other ways for that) - just wish to provide relay capacity while keeping these activities hidden from our ISP (who I detest). Have a second identical gateway going to a different VPN which I might be willing to convert also - if I could just get the first to work.

Believe I found the main problem....torrc had a hidden .txt suffix (rolling eyes). Now it shows to be reading the configuration.

New problem? It claims I haven't inserted contact information - but I believe I have.

```
Apr 23 14:12:40.799 [notice] Tor 0.2.9.10 (git-1f6c8eda0073f464) running on Windows 7 with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2k and Zlib 1.2.8.
Apr 23 14:12:40.799 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 23 14:12:40.819 [notice] Read configuration file "C:\Users\VPNProxy\AppData\Roaming\tor\torrc".
Apr 23 14:12:40.829 [warn] Path for GeoIPFile (<default>) is relative and will resolve to C:\Users\Guest\tor\tor\<default>. Is this what you wanted?
Apr 23 14:12:40.829 [warn] Path for GeoIPv6File (<default>) is relative and will resolve to C:\Users\Guest\tor\tor\<default>. Is this what you wanted?
Apr 23 14:12:40.829 [notice] Your ContactInfo config option is not set. Please consider setting it, so we can contact you if your server is misconfigured or something else goes wrong.
Apr 23 14:12:40.829 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 1535 MB. You can override this by setting MaxMemInQueues by hand.
Configuration was valid
```

What am I missing here?

Update. This is my current torrc:

Security refinements welcomed. I'm very nervous tor relay only functions with admin privileges.

```
 ORPort 9803
 Nickname worfdog
 RelayBandwidthRate 100 KBytes
 ContactInfo Bat Shit <services+torelay AT doemail.org>
 DirPort 10803
 Exitpolicy reject *:*
```

Comment: The ContactInfo isn't required, its just helpful. The logs look fine, it's starting properly. Can you provide the contents of the torrc file too?

Comment: How can I get this file to you? When I paste it into the original help request window - it strips out the pound sign comment symbols. Can't find a way to attach the file either.

Comment: It probably doesn't strip them, they're likely being used as the markdown symbols, instead put 4 spaces infront of the lines to mark them as "pre-formatted", or use the button to mark them as pre-formatted/code so they're not interpreted as markdown.

Comment: Arrg, only inserted 1 space. And it screwed up. Sorry.

Comment: The likelihood is that Tor isn't using the torrc you've provided. When you start tor, issue the command `tor` with the `-f` flag followed by the path to your torrc.

Comment: No, it claims it read the file at startup. But it apparently can only reach that default directory (where I stuck the torrc) when I run with elevated privileges. Am now at the point where I don't know what to do. Shut it down again and try that -f flag to point tor to a reachable directory - or just leave it be. Do most windows users run tor with elevated privileges? Is there a "best practices" here? Tor is running under EMET, but if something gets into that code - they could reach out. Have a fail safe with rollback software like they use in public libraries - but that's a new mess.

Comment: You're clearly missing something with how you're running it if it can't read the file it's probably related to permissions and a general error in your attempt to run it as a low privileged user.

Comment: You are correct. But keep in mind, I carefully observed the Tor defaults and have double checked file locations. They are correct. So at this point, I just need to know if tor.exe must have admin privileges to run, or if I can fudge running tor.exe from a limited user account (guest account is my preference). I know my OpenVPN client has *always* required admin privileges to run - but have accepted that because it directly handles the NIC (a windows design decision?). In contrast, tor.exe only touches a virtual connection? Why does it need admin?

Comment: It doesn't require administrator privileges to run.

Comment: Arrgh...guess I have more work to do then. I was able to get tor.exe to run in the client mode from a guest account.

Comment: One good thing..even if it gets infected from running it like this, I can just push button restore the initial snapshot and it returns to "good as new". At least until some creep whacks it again :(

Comment: 864V4 Connections so far with an observed bandwidth of 109KB/sec ( I throttled it with that 100K torrc entry). (shrug) Modest relay for sure - but it's still a relay.

Comment: Glad it's up and running, from the looks of the logs it was trying to reach across C:\Users\guest to C:\Users\VPNProxy which might be why permissions were an issue.